# Dotnetnuke is very slow when form will big at edit mode

Tags: dotnetnuke

There have been some reports that Dynamic Forms can be very slow in edit mode and becomes cumbersome, especially when creating a large form with a variety of field types. Actually, I have bigs form contain Textboxes, radio button list, dropdowns, file uploads, checkboxes, and grid view. Actually, I am converting my old asp.net web application to Dotnetnuke for CMS purpose. Please suggest following.

1) Is possible to convert asp.net web form application to DotNetNuke.

2) we can use gridview option in DotNetNuke.

3) I have two types of logins **user** and **admin**. Admin can add a gallery, add news and see user submitted forms and he/she will shortlist and reject base on performance forms.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, but a forms module is probably a better choice.
2) I think yes, but you'd have to create that in a custom module.  Again, a forms module is a better choice.
3) Yes, you can give varying degrees of administrative control based on user roles.

Besides Dynamic Forms, you might also want to evaluate Action Forms (DNNSharp) and Live Forms (Mandeeps).  There are other choices, and I have had success using digForm (DigNuke).